# Paramiko SFTPClient - Setting missing host key policy?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I know with Paramiko's SSHClient class, you can set a relaxed missing host key policy like so:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
```

However, I'm opening a file stream via SFTP (not SSHClient), like so:

```
t = paramiko.Transport((process['hostname'], 22))
keyfile = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file('./id_dsa')
t.connect(username = 'user', pkey = keyfile)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
```

I couldn't locate anything in the docs for setting a missing host key policy via Transport, or SFTPClient.

Is there any way to achieve the same thing using SFTPClient?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can get SFTP client from SSH client by using `open_sftp()`.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

sftp = ssh.open_sftp() 
sftp.get('remotefile', 'localfile')
```

Though I haven't tested this.

Comment: I have a connection that I can not make an ssh connection because of the restrictions on the server. How do I check the policy using transport and sftp clients?